# Удалить перенос строки, если строка не пустая

Tags: linux, shell

Как средствами shell удалить перенос строки только в том случае, если строка не пустая?

Допустим есть файл, содержащий

```
q
w
e

r
t

y
```

Из него необходимо получить файл, содержащий

```
qwe

rt

y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file | sed 's/^$/\r\r/' | tr -d '\n' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

сначала в пустые строки вставляем пару символов [*carriage return* (0x0d, \r)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8), которые на последнем шаге заменим на символы *line feed* (0x0a, \n).

затем удаляем все символы *line feed*.

последний шаг: заменяем все *carriage return* на *line feed*.

---

вместо *carriage return* можно использовать любой другой символ, который заведомо не встречается в исходном файле.

---

результирующий файл получится без завершающего символа \n, что не принято у текстовых файлов. чтобы этого избежать, можно в программе для *sed* сразу добавлять в конце последней строки символ-подмену:

```
$ cat file | sed 's/^$/\r\r/;$s/$/\r/' | tr -d '\n' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

---

**обновление**

в общем-то, можно обойтись только вызовом *sed*, без символа-подмены, и без *tr*, но программа для *sed* получается несколько громоздкой:

```
$ cat /tmp/file | sed -n '/^$/!H;/^$/{x;s/\n//g;/^$/!s/$/\n/;p};${x;s/\n//g;p}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на perl:

```
perl -0pe 's/\N\K\n(?!\n|$)//g;' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Выводим содержимое файла | **не** выводим начало-конец строк (пустые) | удаляем unix-перенос строки.

```
cat file | grep -v ^$ | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Нет пустые строки могут встречаться и в документе непосредсвенно.

Comment: Все пустые строки грепом будут игнориться. Тогда дополни вопрос и дай 2 примера содержимого файлов: оригинала и как ты хочешь его видеть после преобразования.